# Set text size with dimens - Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-resources, dimensions, android-screen-support, android-resolution

I want to change text size by screen resolution to phones and i used with dimens like this:

[image]

I set by Screen Height and its works fine with phone like naxus 5 or pixel 3XL.
My question is if this is how I should define? What did I do well enough to fit any cell phone and tablet?

Answer (score 0):

The files listed above will most certainly cover any android device or tablet.  You can always add more configurations if you eventually find a device that isn't utilizing the correct dimens.xml that you desire.  There are so many android devices of all shapes and sizes, it is hard to have a coverall approach by using xml files.

Another option would be to programmatically set the the font size based on a ratio of the screen dimensions which can be found below.  Exactly how to best do that would depend on how your app is set up.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Using the height and width above you could change the font size. However, Where exactly to do that in your code depends entirely on how your app is set up.